C# TreeView NodeMouseclick or Click function shows previous selected
Hi I am facing a peculiar issue. I am using a Windows Form (.NET Framework) and have created a TreeView with a sample list from database. I would like to display the details of the selected node by the user. But when I click on say Child Finance node, the message box shows previously selected Inventory instead of Child Finance and then updates the Parent Value textbox as well to Inventory. I am sharing my code and the image of what's going on.  I have already tried click/mouseclick and then tried the treenodemouseclickeventargs. Can some one help me? I am not sure if there is something in my code I should work on.
private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sample;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    String Sequel = "SELECT MAINMNU,MENUPARVAL,STATUS FROM [sample].[accounts].[MNUPARENT]";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sequel, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        parentNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["MAINMNU"].ToString());
        PopulateTreeView(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MENUPARVAL"].ToString()), parentNode);

    }
    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}
private void PopulateTreeView(int parentId, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sample;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    String Seqchildc = "SELECT MENUPARVAL,FRM_NAME,MNUSUBMENU FROM sample.accounts.MNUSUBMENU WHERE MENUPARVAL=" + parentId + "";
    SqlDataAdapter dachildmnuc = new SqlDataAdapter(Seqchildc, conn);
    DataTable dtchildc = new DataTable();
    dachildmnuc.Fill(dtchildc);
    TreeNode childNode;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtchildc.Rows)
    {
        if (parentNode == null)
            childNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["FRM_NAME"].ToString());
        else
            childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(dr["FRM_NAME"].ToString());
        PopulateTreeView(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MNUSUBMENU"].ToString()), childNode);
        
    }
}
private void treeView1_MouseSingleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(menuItem);
        textBox_parentVal.Text = menuItem;
    }
}



In the event handler use argument to get clicked node, rather than TreeView.SelectedNode property.

After my test, your problem lies in the treeView1_MouseSingleClick event handler. You used treeView1.SelectedNode.Text. In some cases, SelectedNode may lag behind in displaying the previous selected value. Therefore, when you click a new node, SelectedNode has not yet updated to the node you currently clicked.
You can try to change var menuItem = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text; to var menuItem = e.Node.Text;. e is an object of type TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs, which directly points to the currently clicked node.
In this way, menuItem will directly obtain the text of the node you clicked, and will not be affected by the delay in updating SelectedNode.

Hi @Ajay Shah, I'd like to know if this answer worked for you, if so, please mark it, and if you find another way, please post it so that others with the same problem can find the answer quickly.
